# Is it possible to insert data with ajax request by only using the csrf field instead of token?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to insert data with CSRF field. I really don't have the idea of CSRF token. (new to laravel). I'm getting unknown status error in /classwork/insert.

```
//This is my ajax function: I really can't understand what is wrong with the code.
```

Is it possible to do ajax calls with only using {{csrf-field}}

```
function insertData(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({

        url: '/classwork/insert',
        method: 'post',
        data : 'data',
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);          
        }

    });
}

//This is my controller and Route:

public function insertTask(Request $request){
  $task = new Task;
  $task->task = $request->task;
  $task->save();
}

//this is my route
Route::post('/classwork/insert', 'TaskController@insertTask');
```

Comment: Hi @rakesh shrestha when you pass POST method  compulsory pass CSRF Token like this headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}

Comment: Thanks! but I've got another issues .. can you help ? message
:
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'task' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `tasks` (`task`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, 2018-04-03 16:49:42, 2018-04-03 16:49:42))"

Answer (score 1):

Make a genric ajaxRequest function. Add this to meta

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then in your global ajax function do this;

```
public function ajaxRequest(options){
$.ajaxSetup({
 headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
 }
});
$.ajax({

    url: option.url,
    method: option.method,
    data : option.data,
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);          
    }

});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way

Add this before ajax calling

```
$.ajaxSetup({
 headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
 }
});
```

Comment: now i get a error something like this :
message
:
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'task' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `tasks` (`task`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, 2018-04-03 16:49:42, 2018-04-03 16:49:42))"

Comment: In your code you are not sending any data that's why a null value is inserting to database table. So error shows. Try sending data in the data attribute of ajax function

Comment: I've already serialized the data.. It doesn't pass as a json? .. how can I pass the data now.. afsal

Comment: try adiing this in ajax function dataType: 'json'

Answer (score 0):

Please always add this meta tag in main blade page

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And instead of old scholl jquery ajax.. just use Axios. simple and very easy. it already detect the csrd-token meta tag. so no need to do in the form or header

change this

```
$.ajax({

    url: '/classwork/insert',
    method: 'post',
    data : 'data',
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);          
    }

});
```

to this

```
axios.post('/classwork/insert', data)
.then(function(response) { 
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!! .. but now I'm getting another error .. can you please help again @zeroOne .. message
:
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'task' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `tasks` (`task`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, 2018-04-03 17:00:48, 2018-04-03 17:00:48))"

Comment: it means 'task' value cannot be null.. please check whether the 'task' variable have value in it

Comment: and why is axios not defined sir